# How to change bytes of file in HexEditor terminal

Tags: hex

How can I add 4 characters to the start of a file by using the hexeditor (xdd) in terminal?

Comment: Are you referring to `xxd`? if so, that's really a hex *viewer* rather than a hex editor

Comment: (`echo -e "0xabcd"; cat file) >file.new; mv file.new file`.